Converting SQLAlchemy models to Pydantic model
I have the following structure of folders:
app/
├── __init__.py
├── database/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── models/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── author.py
│       └── book.py
├── schemas/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── author.py
│   └── book.py
└── main.py

My database models are:

database/models/author.py

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from app.database import Base


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Authors"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=True)
    gender = Column(String, nullable=True)

    books = relationship("Book", back_populates="author")


database/models/book.py

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from app.database import Base


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Books"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=True)
    price = Column(Integer, default=0)
    isbn = Column(String(13), nullable=True)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Authors.id"))

    author = relationship("Author", back_populates="books")


database/models/__init__py (very simple)

from .author import Author
from .book import Book

__all__ = [
    "Author",
    "Book",
]

Noe my Pydantic models are:

schemas/author.py

from __future__ import annotations
from pydantic import BaseModel


class AuthorBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str | None = None
    gender: str | None = None


class AuthorCreate(AuthorBase):
    pass


class AuthorUpdate(AuthorBase):
    name: str | None = None


class Author(AuthorBase):
    id: int
    books: list['BookBase'] = []    # noqa: F821

    class Config:
        from_attributes=True


schemas/book.py

from __future__ import annotations
from pydantic import BaseModel


class BookBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    price: int
    isbn: str


class BookCreate(BookBase):
    author_id: int


class BookUpdate(BookBase):
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None
    price: int | None = None
    isbn: str | None = None
    author_id: int | None = None


class Book(BookBase):
    id: int
    author: "AuthorBase"   # noqa: F821

    class Config:
        from_attributes=True


schemas/init.py

from .book import Book, BookCreate, BookUpdate, BookBase
from .author import Author, AuthorCreate, AuthorUpdate, AuthorBase

Book.model_rebuild()
Author.model_rebuild()

__all__ = [
    "Author",
    "AuthorCreate",
    "AuthorUpdate",
    "AuthorBase",
    "Book",
    "BookCreate",
    "BookUpdate",
    "BookBase",
]

Now to the real question! I'm using FastAPI and have a route on GET /book/{book_id}, which returns a book information. First, the route was returning an instance of the database model Book, and everything was working fine. But then, to make things better, I wanted to return a Pydantic Book object. But I just can't simply convert one model to another. When I call:
schemas.Book.model_validate(db_book)

I always get an error, saying:
Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of AuthorBase [type=model_type, input_value=<app.database.models.auth...bject at 0x78f76c994590>, input_type=Author]``

But I just cant seem to fix it. I know the DB model return an Author object and model_validade expects an AuthorBase. But since I'm calling model_rebuind shouldnt everything works fine? If I declare AuthorBase in the same file as the Book schema, it works, but I wanted to have separate files for each schema.
Does anyone knows why this is happening? What am I getting wrong about Pydantic and SQLAlchemy models?

I suggest you use the SQLModel library. That's basically a fancy wrapper that maps Pydantic to SQLAlchemy entities.

try adding from_attributes = True to the AuthorBase's config

Your Book model expects as AuthorBase object, but your AuthorBase object isn't configured to load anything from attributes. You probably want to set the model configuration on the base object (as you did for BookBase), not on the one that inherits from it (and use model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True) if you're on Pydantic v2).
